Fraction bar too short
When I have a really long fraction, it tends to be too short:
$\frac{11111111111111111111111}1$
Video:

Image:

This happens in both the preview and in the post.

Interesting. It looks ok to me: https://i.sstatic.net/oTzI60xA.png (Windows, Google Chrome, HTML-CSS as the math renderer.)

@Lucenaposition FWIW, using Microsoft Edge on Windows $10$, with the default HTML-CSS MathJax renderer, it also looks fine to me.

@Lucenaposition, Please don't respond to requests for clarification with a comment.  Instead, [edit] the post to add that information.  I've done that for you, but I'm letting you know for the future.  Thank you.

The HTML-CSS output renderer is the oldest and most fragile.  It is also has browser and OS dependencies, so your results may vary depending on which you are using.
At the time the HTML-CSS renderer was written, the results were not very consistent across browsers, and MathJax tried to compensate for that by actually measuring the various pieces as it put them together.  For example, the numerator and denominator of the fraction are measured in order to determine the size of the fraction line.  The problem is that MathJax had to determine the font's em size empirically by measuring some test DOM elements that were given in whole-number pixel units, and that gives results that are not entirely accurate.  So the pixel-to-em ratio is not perfect, and that means that MathJax's knowledge of the size of things is imperfect as well.  The longer an item is, the more that inaccuracy matters, and you see that in the fractions in your example.
The other renderers (CommonHTML and SVG) should produce better results.  The HTML-CSS renderer is the slowest, least accurate, and most fragile of the three; choosing another one is usually a good idea.

Addendum added to respond to the comment of Xander Henderson.

A kludgy fix is to use manual spacing.  For example, consider $$\frac{~~~~~11111~~~~~}{1}$$ which is created via
$$\frac{~~~~~11111~~~~~}{1}$$

In MathJax, you can use (for example) either ~ or \; for spacing.

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$

Don't do this. The problem is with the way that fractions are rendered by some browsers. Doing as you suggest might make things look okay to the person writing the post, but will likely end up making thinks low terrible to almost everyone else.

I am not suggesting that the composer add 5 spaces before and after; that was just for illustrative purposes.  Instead, I am suggesting that the original poster might consider adding one space.
Consider the following implementation
$$\frac{~11111~}{1}, \tag1 $$
which was created via \frac{~11111~}{1}.
I don't think that (1) above looks that bad, so I stand by the recommendation.

Don't do this. The problem is with the way that fractions are rendered by some browsers. Doing as you suggest might make things look okay to the person writing the post, but will likely end up making thinks low terrible to almost everyone else.

@XanderHenderson Addendum added to the end of my answer, to respond to your comment.
